# How can I reset my vlc media player back to its original settings after someone has messed all the settings up for playing movies?

Tags: video, vlc

I usually use vlc media player for my movies but my little cousin has somehow messed all the settings up and now when I try to play a movie, I can't watch it properly. The player still works but its like all the settings like the colours and saturation and the settings that make the picture ok are messed up and I don't know how to put them back to normal.

Is it possible to reset VLC settings to default?

Comment: Does `vlc --reset-config` work?

Comment: It did for me, thank you

Answer (score 10):

**Option 1:**

Delete the `~/.config/vlc` and `~/.cache/vlc` folders.

To do this execute  : `rm -r ~/.config/vlc ~/.cache/vlc`

**Note** : Old versions of VLC had the data stored in `~/.vlc`

**Option 2:**

Execute : `vlc --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache`

**Option 3:**

Open VLC --> **`Tools`**-->**`Preferences`**-->**`Reset Preferences`**

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the preferences using the menu:

> Tools → Preferences